# AngularFire auth failing silently on Facebook login

Tags: angularjs, debugging, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I'm trying to log my user into Facebook using AngularFire auth. When I click login I see the error event fire - angularFireAuth:error but the err array is empty. I have no idea what is wrong or how to debug. Any ideas?

View:

```
<div ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
       <div id="loginDiv">
           <a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
         <span ng-show="user">
           {{user.name}}
         <a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
         </span>
         <a href="#" ng-hide="user" ng-click="login()">Login</a>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFireAuth',
function UsersCtrl($scope, angularFireAuth) {
var url = 'https://inviter-dev.firebaseio.com';
angularFireAuth.initialize(url, {scope: $scope, name: "user"});


$scope.login = function() {
    console.debug("logging in")
    angularFireAuth.login("facebook");
};

$scope.logout = function() {
    angularFireAuth.logout();
};

$scope.$on("angularFireAuth:login", function(evt, user) {
  console.debug("login event", user)
});
$scope.$on("angularFireAuth:logout", function(evt) {
   console.debug("logout event", user)
});
$scope.$on("angularFireAuth:error", function(evt, err) {
    console.debug("auth error", err)
  // There was an error during authentication.
});


 }
]);
```

Comment: after stepping through the code it looks like it is an issue with the Simple Login object - Simple Login not initialized. I don't know how to resolve but gives me something to research.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out, please post a new question if you have any other trouble!

Answer (score 0):

> This problem seemed to be related to an issue of placement and ordering of js dependencies. I moved these dependencies into HTML Head and it works:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-auth-client.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">   </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular/angularFire.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
```